# Java File Handling Editing records

Tags: java

I made a code for my system which would update a record in my text file database but I cant seem to make it work. The code doesnt have any error. its just not doing what I intend it to do

```
public static void Update() throws Exception {
    File tempfile2 = new File("temp.txt");
    tempfile2.createNewFile();
    FileInputStream tempFStream = new FileInputStream(tempfile2);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tempFStream));

    System.out.print("Product Number: ");
    String searchnum = br.readLine();

    try {
        LoadFile();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            String record[] = list.get(i).split(",");
            if (!searchnum.equals(record[0])) {
                found = true;
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempfile2, true);
                fw.write(record[0] + "," + record[1] + "," + record[2] + "," + record[3] + "," + record[4] + "," + record[5] + "\r\n");
                fw.close();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            String record[] = list.get(i).split(",");

            if (searchnum.equals(record[0])) {
                found = true;

                System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t       PIXBOX PHOTOBOOTH");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\tRecord Found:");
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\tProduct Number  : " + record[0]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tCategory      : " + record[1]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tProduct Name  : " + record[2]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tPrice [m/d/y] : " + record[3]);
                System.out.println("\t\t\tQuantity      : " + record[4]);
                System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t--------------------------------");

                System.out.print("\t\t\tAre you sure you want to replace the records?<Y/N>: ");
                String del = br.readLine();

                if (del.equals("Y") || del.equals("y")) {

                    LoadFile();

                    System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t       PIXBOX PHOTOBOOTH");
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
                    System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t------Update Record Form------");
                    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\tProduct Number      : ");
                    int prodnum = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                    System.out.print("\t\t\tCategory        : ");
                    String cat = br.readLine();

                    System.out.print("\t\t\tProduct Name        :");
                    String prodname = br.readLine();
                    System.out.print("\t\t\tPrice: ");
                    String price = br.readLine();
                    System.out.print("\t\t\tQuantity    : ");
                    String quan = br.readLine();

                    read.close();
                    database.delete();
                    boolean rename = false;

                    if (rename = tempfile2.renameTo(database)) {
                        InsertRecords(prodnum, cat, prodname, price, quan);
                        System.out.println("\t\t\tSuccessfully Edited!");
                        exiting();
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("Edit Failed!");
                    }
                } else if (del.equals("N") || del.equals("n")) {
                    MainMenu();
                }
            }
            if (!searchnum.equals(record[1])) {
                System.out.println("\n\t\t\tNo Record Found.");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                exiting();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("File Empty!");
    }

}
public static void LoadFile()throws Exception
{
    list.clear();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(database);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    row = 0; 
    while(read.ready())
    {
        list.add(read.readLine());
        row++;
    }   
    read.close();
}
```

Everytime I run this... it would work until Product Number: *User input*     and after entering a number it would directly display File is empty which is at the end of the program. its as if the try/catch is ignored. I definitely did something wrong but I dont know what I did wrong. Anyone shed me some light? Thanks

and with the e.printStackTrace(); here's what displayed after entering a product number...

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundException:5
  at SnackTimeInventorySystem.Update<SnackTimeInventorySystem.java:525>
  at SnackTimeInventorySystem.MainMenu<SnackTimeInventorySystem.java:66>
  at SnackTimeInventorySystem.Login<SnackTimeInventorySystem.java:369>
  at SnackTimeInventorySystem.main<SnackTimeInventorySystem.java:14>
```

Comment: well you can print the exception trace in the catch block and see what causes it. your program right now gives no information about what caused the error

Comment: *"its as if the try/catch is ignored"* No, there is an exception in that `try` block, so it jumps into the `catch` block, where you ignore the exception and just print a meaningless *"File Empty!"*. Use `e.printStackTrace();` instead to see what the exception is. It will help you (and us) to tell what exactly went wrong. Btw, please add the source of the `LoadFile` method to the question.

Comment: @Tom well here's the method for Load File

Comment: Where? And please don't post code into the comments, update your question instead. And please fix that problem in the `catch` block and then update your question with the stacktrace of the exception. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the problem is this `record[5]`. Please check that each line, which you split here `String record[] = list.get(i).split(",")` has 5 commas, so that `record` array has **6** entries.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I overlooked it. problem solved :) although there's a new problem but I think I can manage it this time. I appreciate your time and help you gave me

Comment: No worries. And if you need help with the next problem, then feel free to create a new question for it. And keep in mind: never ignore an exception :).

Comment: Btw: if you have found the problem, then also feel free to write an answer for your question. You can accept it then.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I only had 5 entries on my array but declared 6 entries to be written

```
System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t       PIXBOX PHOTOBOOTH");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t*******************************");
            System.out.println("\n\t\t\tRecord Found:");
            System.out.println("\n\t\t\tProduct Number  : " + record[0]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tCategory      : " + record[1]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tProduct Name  : " + record[2]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tPrice [m/d/y] : " + record[3]);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tQuantity      : " + record[4]);
            System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\t--------------------------------");

fw.write(record[0] + "," + record[1] + "," + record[2] + "," + record[3] + "," + record[4] + "," + record[5] + "\r\n");
```

So I just had to delete `record[5]` and fixed the problem thanks to Tom